# How i start my project using page object model framework in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to do my automation testing project following a page object model using Selenium's webdriver framework. Does anybody knows about the pom framework, please explain  How i start my project using page object model framework in selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a small base project on GitHub written in Java and using Maven.

Have a look, it might be a good starting point for you;
https://github.com/ECiurleo/webdriverBase

Comment: @EClurieo hai.. What is your opinion about page object model framework? Does it useful?  I am a new in the testing field. Actually I don't know about page object model framework. could you explain in simple words. how the pom framework is good comparing with other frameworks like modular, keyword, data and hybrid driven frameworks?

Comment: hai who to run this file?

Comment: Instructions on how to run are in the read me.  In most IDE you can normally select the TestNG xml (custom_tests.xml) right click and select run.  To answer your other question may need a separate question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

It is a pattern to create `Object Repository` for web UI elements.

**Structural Implementation:**

In POM for each web page in the application there should be corresponding page class. That Page class will find the `WebElements` of that web page and also contains `Page methods` which perform operations on those WebElements.

Name of these methods should be given as per the task they are performing i.e., if a loader is waiting for payment gateway to be appear, POM method name can be `waitForPaymentScreenDisplay()`.

Some Links which help you more

[Link 1](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/abstracting-selenium-tests-using-page-object-model)
[Link 2](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/)
[Link 3](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2015/02/page-object-model-for-selenium-webdriver.html)

Comment: Excuse me. there were keyword driven , hybrid driven modular driven and data driven framework and also page object model framwork are there which framework will i select? which is better for use?

Comment: @AntonyNaveen Start using page object initially..

Comment: i would like to know about the framwork in selenium webdriver. I am learning basics of selenium webdriver. next i want to do my project using a framework. how to start? what will i do?

Comment: @AntonyNaveen Please read from above Links . That will help you very well explained.